# How do I determine what child class i'm referencing in a list?

Tags: c#, oop, abstraction

I have a List of about 100 objects which just so happen to be tiles. It looks like this:

```
 List<Tile> Tiles;
```

Elsewhere in my code I have classes that derive from the tile base class, I'll use house for this example:

```
 public class house : Tile
```

Inside of the list up top I have added different types of tiles to the data structure:

```
 Tiles.add(new house());
 Tiles.add(new church()); //ect. ect.
```

My question is how do I know which tiles are churches or houses if I where to reference that list through a control structure like a for-loop. Basically I need to compare two tiles of different types together. Is it even possible to know which child class I am referencing? I'm sure there's an easy explanation to this however I'm not very well versed when it comes to Object-Oriented programming so i'm not even entirely sure what i'm supposed to be looking for when it comes to help.

Comment: I recommend a re-design so you dont need to know what the child types are. Add a virtual method like @MarcGravell suggests in his answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various options here

- you can use `is`/`as` to check a particular object to see if it is of a particular type
- you could add a discriminator - maybe an enum property such as `.TileType` (compare: Expression.NodeType)
- you could instead use a `virtual` method so that you don't **need** to know what the type is: you just say "do whatever your type does here" (i.e. invoke the virtual method)

Comment: +1, I agree, with a proper design the code shouldnt need to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "is" operator - "Tiles[index] is house"

but in general this is a bad thing to do - **you break the oop principles**

what you should do it to implement the method on the derived classes so they will know how to do the logic themselfs and you won't have to use the "is" operator.

Comment: If you will write what you are trying to do i can try writing an example

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this:

```
foreach (var house in Tiles.OfType<house>()) { ..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Tile tile in Tiles)
{
    if (tile is house)
    {
        // do things
    }
}
```

You can use the is keyword like above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.GetType()` to get the Type of the current instance.

[Refer MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx)